# How to create a google maps field in KeystoneJS framework

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I would like to add a google maps field in my page, where I am using KeystoneJS as admin panel. I cannot see any field type to implement. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can start with an field type Location: http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-location

```
location        : { type: Types.Location, enableMapsAPI:true },
```

This field can save the address also you can use the underscore method: googleLookup(region, update, callback) - autodetect the full address and lng, lat from the stored value. then you need some code to display the map.